# Escaping Special Characters for MS Access Query

Tags: c#, sql, regex, ms-access, jet

I want to store these characters " '^+%&/()=?_ " via an insert query for an ms access database. How do I do this and prevent from every cases?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "prevent from every cases"

Comment: secure code for every chars, maybe a regex or a builtin method in .net. I'm getting Syntax error in query expression for a querystring which I generate with string builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using a parameterized query (see Adrian's Answer)  you can use a Query Definition  with a parameter and call it.

For example you could create a query named qry_InsSomeTable with the following sql

```
PARAMETERS P_SomeField Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO tbl_SomeTable (  P_SomeField )
VALUES (P_SomeField );
```

Then you could call like you would any stored procedure

```
using(var cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Whatever.mdb")
{
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "qry_InsSomeTable";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_SomeField", "'^+%&/()=?_ ");

    cn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 


}
```

Its particularly helpful when you have a table with a bunch of fields

For example

```
  cmd.CommandText = @"Insert  Into TableWithAlotofFields 
                    (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5,...)
                    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?..)";


  cmd.Parameters.Add("value1");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("value2");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("value3");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("value4");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("value5");
```

vs.

Query already define in  Access as

```
 PARAMETERS P_field1Text Text ( 255 ), P_field2 Number, P_field3 text(15), ...;
  Insert Into TableWithAlotofFields 
  (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5,...)
  VALUES(P_field1, P_field2, P_field3, P_field4, P_field5,...)
```

then in c#

```
 cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "qry_InsSomeTable";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field1", "value1");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field2", "value2");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field3", "value3");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field4", "value4");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field5", "value5");
```

However as @David-W-Fenton points out the names on the parameters are ignored and only the position is taken into account.
e.g.

*This*

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field1", "value1");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field2", "value2");
```

*is not equivalent to*

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field2", "value2");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_field1", "value1");
```

So it seems it mostly stylistic in the differences.

Comment: thank you. I can't believe I haven't tried this before asking it here. I thought it would be the same with parameters.

Comment: There is a problem with parameters and MS Access. Any text can only have a maximum of 255 characters which means updating memo type data in this way is not an option.

Comment: Also, I believe that none of the drivers for use of Jet/ACE from outside Access support named parameters, so the parameter names would be replaced with question marks, so far as I understand this (as is the case in the next-to-last example in your question).

Comment: @Remou in the case of a memo field you define your Text parameter and omit the length e.g. `PARAMETER P_MEMO text;` I don't know how big of as string you can get in there. I stopped testing the limits at 5MB. I don't know what led you to believe that memo fields were a problem

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I never noticed that the names weren't being used as I would always match my order to the Insert query. I updated my answer

Comment: @Conrad Apologies, you are talking about OleDB, my experience was with ADO, where it is a problem. I cannot find the reference at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Use [parameterized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) `INSERT` statement.

It looks like your code is assembling the SQL command string. I have to tell you: if that's the case, it makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: don't think the SqlClient will work to well on an Access Database.

Comment: OleDbClient should work just fine, though.  And OleDbCommand works quite similarly to SqlCommand (at least from the user's POV).

Answer (score 0):

To insert special Characters you should enclose the special characters in brackets ([]). I hope this helps.

Comment: both "['^+%&/()=?_]" and "['][^][+][%][&][/][(][)][=][?][_]" don't work

Comment: That's because the brackets syntax is not applicable to Jet SQL.

Answer (score 0):

on Visual Studio you must to convert the single to double character

i.e.:

```
sql = replace(sql, "'", "''");
```